# C++ code to get the cpu utilization in Linux

Tags: c++, linux

I try to get the cpu utilization on my Ubuntu 20.04 but I get always the same informations:

```
Utilization cpu = 0
Utilization core 8 = 100
```

I followed the instructions explained here:

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Linux_CPU_utilization

Here is the function I made to read the cpu utilization:

```
uint8_t CPU::getPercentageCpu(std::string str, std::ifstream &cpu_stat) const {
    uint8_t i;
    uint8_t n = 0;
    uint32_t time;
    float idle;
    float total_time = 0;
    float cpu_utilization;
    char number;

    cpu_stat.ignore(5, ' '); // Skip the 'cpu' prefix
    getline(cpu_stat,str);

    for(i = 0; i < 9 ; i++) {
        time = 0;
        number = str.at(n);
        do {
            time = time * 10 + (uint16_t(number) - 48);
            n++;
            number = str.at(n);
        } while(number != ASCII_SP);

        total_time += time;
        n++;

        if(i==3)
            idle = time;
    }

    cpu_utilization = (1-(idle/total_time)) *100;

    return static_cast<uint8_t>(cpu_utilization);
}

uint8_t CPU::getCPUUsage() const {

    std::ifstream cpu_stat;
    std::string str;
    uint8_t cpu_utilization;

    cpu_stat.open("/proc/stat");

    if(cpu_stat.is_open()) {
        getline(cpu_stat,str);
        cpu_utilization = this->getPercentageCpu(str, cpu_stat);
        cpu_stat.close();
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open /proc/stat \n";
        return -1;
    }
    return cpu_utilization;
}

uint8_t Core::getCPUUsage(uint8_t CPUNumber) const {
    /*
     * CPUNumber is the core number, it starts at 0
     */

    uint8_t i;
    uint8_t cpu_utilization;
    std::ifstream cpu_stat;
    std::string str;

    cpu_stat.open("/proc/stat");

    if(cpu_stat.is_open()) {
        /* skip all cpu infos until we get the good cpu */
        for(i = 0; i< (CPUNumber+1); i++)
            getline(cpu_stat,str);

        cpu_utilization = this->getPercentageCpu(str, cpu_stat);
        cpu_stat.close();
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open /proc/stat \n";
        return -1;
    }

    return cpu_utilization;
}
```

In my main, I simply print the result:

```
#include "CPU.hpp"


int main() {

    Core info_proc;
    CPU info_cpu;
    uint8_t core_utilization;
    uint8_t cpu_utilization;

    while(1) {
        core_utilization = info_proc.getCPUUsage(8);
        cpu_utilization = info_cpu.getCPUUsage();

        std::cout << "Utilization cpu = " << static_cast<int>(cpu_utilization) << "\n";
        std::cout << "Utilization core 8 = " << static_cast<int>(core_utilization) << "\n";
        std::cout << "\033[H\033[J";
        usleep(1000000);
    }
}
```

Could you please explain to me what I do wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: The referenced code uses a much more simpler way of reading and parsing the first line in `/proc/stat`, why aren't you simply doing the same thing?

Comment: It's because I want to do this as an exercice to improve my skills in C++ and I don't want to use a code that I don't fully understand. That's why I just read the backgroud chapter and tried to write the code myself.

Comment: Why didn't you understand the code? If you were not familiar with`/proc/stat`'s format, then after reading the background chapter the existing code should now be crystal clear, and it should be clear that this is the simplest way to do that. If you are not familiar enough with C++ to understand what the code is doing, the background chapter on `/proc/stat` format is not going to help you, it is not an excerpt from a C++ textbook that discusses core fundamentals of C++ and the C++ library, that's needed to understand what the code is doing.

Comment: I understood the explanations given in the background part. I'm new to C++ and there are things in the C++ sample code that I don't know yet like vectors. Also, the final results don't interest me, what interests me is to try to program this function alone to learn, so I don't see any point in simply copying and pasting this code. I just want to understand why my code is not working.

Comment: C++ is just too complicated. Trying to learn C++ by trying to understand random code, found in a Google search, is not going to work. The best place to learn about core C++ fundamentals, like vectors, is a C++ textbook. Neither Google, nor Stackoverflow, nor some coding puzzle site, are appropriate replacements for an edited, organized, C++ textbook. Many have tried, to do without one, thinking that the only thing they need to do is run Google searches, and try to do coding puzzles based on the search results. All of them eventually failed, but not after wasting massive amounts of time.